# Magento2 get invoice detail based on tax percent group

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, invoice, tax

I want to get invoice detail based on TaxGroup percentage, How can I achieve this.

Using sales_order_save_after event observer.

```
InvoiceObject = {
    'orderId': 2324234,
    'invoiceId': 443322,
    'amountGroup':[
        {
         VatPercent: 20%,
         InvoiceSubTotal: $200,
         VatTotalAmount: $20
        },{
         VatPercent: 10%,
         InvoiceSubTotal: $100,
         VatTotalAmount: $10
        }
    ]
}
```